# Cannot SSH into my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop from Windows, but can from my laptop Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, windows, timeout

I've recently set up a Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, and installed openSSH.  I can access this desktop via SSH from my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop, but not from Windows 10 PuTTY.  I get no response when I tried to ping from Windows either.  However, I can connect to other servers via SSH from Windows.  I'm a bit confused and not sure where the problem is.  The error I get from putty is Network Connection Time Out.  Any tips will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This may be a problem with your Win10 box and not a Ubuntu issue.  On the machine you are trying to SSH into, open a terminal and type dmesg -wH.  If you see no connection attempt messages then you have something on Win10 that is preventing outbound SSH connections.  If you can't ping a device you definitely will not be able to SSH into it.  Since you can SSH in from another machine (which I'm assuming is on the same subnet as the Win10 PC), sshd and the firewall on the server is probably working.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I will try and check connection attempts later tonight.  I don't think my Win10 box is preventing outbound SSH, since I have no problem SSH into other VMs in the cloud services by using PuTTY.